# Auto rollback MySQL XA transactions

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a variable (e.g. a timeout) in MySQL which automatically rollbacks XA transaction after a period of time?

We are using multiple MySQL databases (schemas) over different connections within our transactions and therefore our database driver MySQLConnector.NET uses XA transactions. Most of the time this works fine, however very rarely a transaction is not completed for reasons unknown, which causes tables to be locked forever. We can manually solve this using the XA recover statement and then rollback the hanging transaction.

Currently we are considering creating a small application which does the rollbacks automatically periodically, but perhaps MySQL has a feature which can handle this?